# create list from columns of data table expression

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the following `dt`:

```
dt <- data.table(a=c(1,1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6,4))
```

That looks like that:

```
> dt
   a b
1: 1 4
2: 1 5
3: 2 6
4: 3 4
```

I'm here aggregating each column by it's unique values and then counting how many uniquye values each column has:

```
 > dt[,lapply(.SD,function(agg) dt[,.N,by=agg])]

   a.agg a.N b.agg b.N
1:     1   2     4   2
2:     2   1     5   1
3:     3   1     6   1
```

So `1` appears twice in `dt` and thus `a.N` is `2`, the same logic goes on for the other values.

But the problem is if this transformations of the original `datatable` have different dimensions at the end, things will get recycled.

For example this `dt`:

```
dt <- data.table(a=c(1,1,2,3,7),b=c(4,5,6,4,4))

> dt[,lapply(.SD,function(agg) dt[,.N,by=agg])]

   a.agg a.N b.agg b.N
1:     1   2     4   3
2:     2   1     5   1
3:     3   1     6   1
4:     7   1     4   3
Warning message:
In as.data.table.list(jval, .named = NULL) :
  Item 2 has 3 rows but longest item has 4; recycled with remainder.
```

That is no longer the right answer because `b.N` should have now only `3` rows and things(vector) got recycled.

This is why I would like to transform the expression `dt[,lapply(.SD,function(agg) dt[,.N,by=agg])]` in a list with different dimensions, with the name of items in the list being the name of the columns in the new transformed `dt`.

A sketch of what I mean is:

```
newlist
$a.agg
1 2 3 7
$a.N
2 1 1 1
$b.agg
4 5 6 4
$b.N
3 1 1
```

Or even better solution would be to get a `datatable` with a track of the columns on another column:

```
    dt_final
   agg N column
    1 2 a
    2 1 a
    3 1 a
    7 1 a
    4 3 b
    5 1 b
    6 1 b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the data in long format and then aggregate by group.

```
library(data.table)

dt_long <- melt(dt, measure.vars = c('a', 'b'))
dt_long[, .N, .(variable, value)]

#   variable value N
#1:        a     1 2
#2:        a     2 1
#3:        a     3 1
#4:        a     7 1
#5:        b     4 3
#6:        b     5 1
#7:        b     6 1
```

In `tidyverse` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  count(name, value)
```

Comment: beautiful :) . `measure.vars = colnames(d)` if you have several thousand columns.